# Operator overloading in Visual c++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
coord front_creature = gs->creatures.front()->get_coord();     //get location of creature closest to base
 coord end = gs->map->get_end();                      //get location of base
    if (front_creature == end) {           //if creature location == base location, then game over
      exit_run_mode();
  }
```

The get_coord and get_end functions return a const coord & and the above code doesn't have any errors. But when I replace it with the following code, visual studio says "no operator '==' matches these operands". I tried placing parentheses around the individual functions, but no luck.

```
if (gs->creatures.front()->get_coord() == gs->map->get_end()) {      
  exit_run_mode();
}
```

Comment: looks like your `operator==` is not a `const` function.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you need your `operator==` to look like this if it is a non-member function:

```
bool operator==(const coord& a, const coord b&);
```

Or, if it is a member function of coord, like this:

```
bool operator==(const coord& rhs) const;
```

When you do something like

```
coord front_creature = gs->creatures.front()->get_coord();
```

you are using the `const coord&` returned by the expression, and using that to initialize a new, non-const `coord`. That is probably why your first example works. Because you are comparing non-const `coords`.

Comment: Missing an equals sign in the third example?

Comment: @TiesonT. On my answer? That's where OP initializes a new `coord` from the expression.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. I thought you were showing how to use the overload. Maybe I should do more than skim next time...